# Deploy Cloud Foundry v2.0 (next generation). BOSH manifest file error

Tags: cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

I successfully deployed full Cloud Foundry on top of vSphere based on this [manual](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/oss-docs/blob/master/bosh/documentation/deploy_cf_vsphere.md) and used [this](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/oss-docs/blob/master/bosh/tutorial/examples/dev124.yml) manifest file like template (I change a lot of it because it's little bit out of date).

Now I realised that I need next version of Cloud Foundry cause space and org features and I started using *_ng templates for cloud controller and appropriate nodes.

I modify my BOSH manifest file and I found few issues with cloud controller DB.
According `cloud_controller_ng.yml.erb`

```
<% db = properties.ccdb_ng.databases.find { |db| db.tag == "cc" } %>
<% db_role = properties.ccdb_ng.roles.find { |role| role.tag == "admin" } %>
db:
  database: postgres://<%= db_role.name %>:<%= db_role.password %>@<%= properties.ccdb_ng.address %>:<%= properties.ccdb_ng.port %>/<%= db.name %>
  max_connections: <%= properties.ccdb_ng.max_connections || 32 %>
  pool_timeout: <%= properties.ccdb_ng.pool_timeout || 10 %>
  log_level: <%= properties.ccng.db_logging_level || "debug2" %>
```

It's require `ccdb_ng` properties in manifest rather `ccdb` (BTW. Why? When Cloud Foundry's next generation become current version this changes become useless. What I missed?):

```
- name: ccdb_postgres
  template: postgres
  instances: 1
  resource_pool: infrastructure
  persistent_disk: 2048
  networks:
  - name: default
    static_ips:
    - 192.168.2.12
  properties:
    db: ccdb_ng
...
  ccdb_ng:
address: 192.168.2.12
port: 5524
pool_size: 10
roles:
- tag: admin
  name: ccadmin
  password: aaaBauWauZZb2
databases:
- tag: cc
  name: appcloud
```

Like result I got an error

```
Preparing configuration
binding configuration: Error filling in template `batch.yml.erb' for `uaa/0' (line 5: undefined method `databases' for nil:NilClass) (00:00:00)
Error                   1/1 00:00:00                                                                

Error 80006: Error filling in template `batch.yml.erb' for `uaa/0' (line 5: undefined method `databases' for nil:NilClass)
```

And that pointed me to this code:

```
<% cc_db = properties.ccdb.databases.find { |db| db.tag == "cc" } %>
<% cc_role = properties.ccdb.roles.find { |role| role.tag == "admin" } %>
```

How you can see it try to find `ccdb` properties. Yes, I can change my manifest file but in this case `cloud_controller_ng.yml.erb` can't found `ccdb_ng` properties.

How can I modify my BOSH manifest file for CloudFoundry to avoid these issues?

I have lot of other questions about that but for now it's major one.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a properties section in the manifest, like in this example;

https://gist.github.com/3148465

For properties.ccdb NOT to evaluate as nil, there would need to be a ccdb entry in the properties section.

Comment: Yes, I do. I know that it require this properties (ccdb) but from other hand cloud_controller_ng require properties.ccdb_ng

Comment: My manifest file [https://gist.github.com/4521103](https://gist.github.com/4521103). How can I modify it to provides ccdb_ng and ccdb properties? For me it make no sense.

Comment: I think this question will yield a better answer on the BOSH users google group - https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/bosh-users the BOSH guys are always pretty quick to answer.